# Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div

Tags: reactjs, cookies, next.js

I'm using `universal-cookie` in Next.js project and this the simple code that return a warning in console:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
import styles from "../styles/Home.module.css";

export default function Home() {
  const cook = new Cookies();
  const [session, setSession] = useState(cook.get("key"));
  const setCookie = () => {
    cook.set("key", "hola", { secure: true });
    setSession(cook.get("key"));
  };
  const deleteCookie = () => {
    cook.remove("key", { secure: true });
    setSession(undefined);
  };

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <button onClick={() => setCookie()}>Save Cookie</button>
      <button onClick={() => deleteCookie()}>Delete Cookie</button>
      {session ? <>I'm in</> : <>I'm out</>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

When "I'M IN" and then I refresh the page the follow warning appear in console:

[image]

I have already looked everywhere for a solution.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

Next.js pre-renders every page on the server.

> By default, Next.js **pre-renders** every page. This means that Next.js generates HTML for each page in advance,
> instead of having it all done by client-side JavaScript.
> Pre-rendering can result in better performance and SEO.
>
> (...) When a
> page is loaded by the browser, its JavaScript code runs and makes the
> page fully interactive (this process is called [hydration](https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/client/hydrateRoot) in React).
>
> — [Next.js, Building Your Application, Rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/rendering)

The hydration issue occurs because the HTML rendered on the browser doesn't match the one generated on the server. In your case this is because `cook.get("key")` returns different things in both.

There are a couple of options to solve the issue.

---

##### #1 Moving setting state to `useEffect`

The first solution is to move setting the state inside a `useEffect`. This forces the state to only be set on the client-side, so no mismatches will occur.

```js
export default function Home() {
    const cook = new Cookies();
    const [session, setSession] = useState();
    
    // `setCookie` and `deleteCookie` code here

    useEffect(() => {
        setSession(cook.get("key"));
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className={styles.container}>
            <button onClick={() => setCookie()}>Save Cookie</button>
            <button onClick={() => deleteCookie()}>Delete Cookie</button>
            {session ? <>I'm in</> : <>I'm out</>}
        </div>
    );
}
```

---

##### #2 Using `next/dynamic` with `{ ssr: false }`

As an alternate solution, the issue can also be circumvented by dynamically importing  the React component with [`next/dynamic`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/dynamic-import#with-no-ssr) using `{ ssr: false }`, wherever the component is used. This prevents the component from being included on the server, and dynamically loads it on the client-side only.

```js
const Home = dynamic(
    () => import('../components/Home'),
    { ssr: false }
)
```

Comment: The easier approach for me this time was `useEffect` hook. Here we can find more info about [why this is happening](https://lihautan.com/hydrating-text-content/). That post helped me a lot to understand more about this weird behavior.

Comment: Great answer. 

Option #1: If the component is made by yourself and you can modify the state logic.

Option #2: If the component uses logic that comes from third party library and cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, juliomalves. What if I'm using https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage, which already uses `useEffect`? I'm curious what you'd recommend for https://stackoverflow.com/q/74022328/470749 Thanks

Comment: @Ryan The problem is how the `useLocalStorage` hook sets its initial state - the `readValue` function returns different things on the server and on the client when the `localStorage` value you're using is set. Either you don't use `useLocalStorage` and write your own logic; or you dynamically import the component where it's used using `next/dynamic` with `{ ssr: false }` (see my #2 solution).

Comment: Thank you. Second option helped me.

Comment: Has this changed in the /app folder in version 13? Neither solution seems to work for me now. I've even tried combining them.

Comment: @Ian This should also apply for the `/app` folder. I'd recommend posting a new question for the issue you're facing.

Comment: It's the same issue. It's actually caching as mentioned by the down voted poster below. Very hard to debug until I deleted the cache.

Comment: Im having the same issue even though im on next13.4.2 and i use the `"use client"` directive for my client components. is that still the expected behavior?

Comment: @benwl Components that use the `'use client'` directive are still rendered on the server too. So yes, it still applies.

Comment: I changed the name of folder then it solved

Comment: Thank you soo much !, the second one fixed my issue, this shows Stackoverflow is still on top from Chatgpt for advance programmers

Answer (score 13):

Using `suppressHydrationWarning` attribute on the html element (which differs) worked for me. It acts only at single level as per documentation below:

https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#suppresshydrationwarning

Comment: Is that the root html element? `<html suppressHydrationWarning="true">` because I'm not sure how this links to react knowing :D

Answer (score 5):

THE FIX for me was:.
replacing this  `import { useTranslation } from "react-i18next";`

by this  `import { useTranslation } from "next-i18next";`

The server rendring use next-i18next package instead of react-i18next and by the way the mismach happens between client and server!

Answer (score 1):

I was using DarkReader addon and it added
`dark reader: --darkreader-inline-bgimage:none;` to my css and caused the issue mismatch between client and server. . .

Try turning it off for your developing page.

Original answer found here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40648

Answer (score 0):

in my case, when I turned my `reactStrictMode` to `false` in my **next.config.js** file, this Warning occurred.
then I had to turn it back to `true` and after that, the Warning disappeared

Answer (score 0):

Using `{ssr: false}` with dynamic import fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, nextjs14, the same error was caused because of this part inside a render function of one server component:

```
<h2>{new Date().toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' })}</h2>
```

Basically, the error was that the text for the current month was rendered in client-side in German and server-side English.

```
Uncaught Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "March" Client: "März"
```

Once i changed my lang in Firefox to English, this discrepancy was gone!

Answer (score -21):

Easy Fix:

Delete the **.next** folder , then run  **npm run build**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have to say, after much messing around. This was actually the issue.