# Nextjs not render as expected and throw "Warning Prop `style` did not match." when using inline style

Tags: reactjs, next.js

### Problem description

I'm facing an issue with my nextjs app. In some components I'd like to add some different style/className between CSR/SSR. Here's a simplified demo code for my problem.

> index.jsx

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function index() {
  const [isServer, setIsServer] = useState(typeof window === 'undefined')
  const style = {
    color: isServer ? 'red' : 'yellow',
  }
  console.log('SeverSide: isServer', isServer)

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsServer(typeof window === 'undefined')
    console.log('ClientSide: isServer', isServer)
  }, [])
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 style={style}>Hi I am Danny</h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Dependencies version

demo project built with npx create-npx-app

```
"dependencies": {
    "next": "11.1.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  }
```

### Expected & actual result

I expected to see the h1 color to be yellow, but here's what I got

[image]

Although the state isServer did change, but the style didn't apply.

I'm not sure if there's any core concepts I'm missing here, really confused about the outcome.

### What I've tried

After googling the error message, most of the posts I can find is related to using styled-component with nextjs, like [this post](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7322). But I don't think that apply to my situation.

Stucked here for quite a while, would appreciate any suggestion.

Let me know if I did not make myself clear,and thank you for reading!

Comment: Maybe instead of inline styling , better you prefer using class name and seperate css?

Comment: @SerkanAKMAN I did try using class name for the issue. But the result still remain the same, just throw different message Warning: Prop `className` did not match. The color of h1 still red.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div NEXTJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66374800/1870780)? The HTML rendered on the browser doesn't match the one generated on the server because `typeof window === 'undefined'` returns different things in both.

Comment: Came here because I had DarkReader addon cause this for me... since it added some styles on the client side... try turning it off!
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/40648

(i know it's not OP's issue)

Answer (score 6):

This quick hack works for me.

```js
const [isServer, setIsServer] = useState(true)
```

Comment: thank you for replying! I did use this approach in my actual project as well, it works fine. Just wondering why is my original approach would cause an issue so I asked the question.