# NextJs Prop style did not match

Tags: javascript, typescript, next.js

I'm building a sorting app and while displaying the array of numbers I get this warning:

```
Warning: Prop `style` did not match. Server: "height:{x}px" Client: "height:{y}px"
```

This is my code:

```
const SortingApp: React.FC = () => {


const fillWithRandom = (quantity: number):number[] => { // array of unique random numbers
    const results: number[] = [];
    while(results.length < quantity){
        let candidateInt = Math.floor(Math.random() * quantity) + 1
        if(results.indexOf(candidateInt) === -1) results.push(candidateInt)
    };

    return results }


const [data, setData] = useState(fillWithRandom(300))


return (
    <>
    <Layout>
    <Navbar />
    <div className="mx-5 flex gap-x-0.5 place-content-center">
        {data.map(x => {
            return (
                <div key={x} className={`w-1 bg-black`} style={{ height: `${x}px` }} />
            )
        })}
    </div>
    </Layout>
    </>
)
```

}

I'm curious to know why the props are different from server to client, since my code is not doing anything too fancy...

Thanks beforehand!

Comment: Data in `data[x]` is filled with random values, so when a component is rendered on the client side you get a different value (most of the time).

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66374800/1870780)? In your case `Math.random()` returns different things on the server and on the client.

Comment: Not necessarily. As stated in that thread, Next.js runs the code both on the server and the client, usually that's no problem but when dealing with random methods it is. The numbers generated at every runtime differ and that causes some weird behaviour client side. I decided to go with react since this will be a static page anyways, I don't really need a server.