# Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching text node for "Bearer..."

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

Using NextJS: I am trying to get the bearer token on my login page component after login (fetch my login endpoint), which comes from the global context of my app (React Context API). It works but I get this error on the console. I assume this is due to the disconnection between the information on the server and on the client-side. Do you know how I can get rid of this error?

**CONTEXT PROVIDER :**

```
  const [token, setToken] = useState(typeof window !== "undefined" ? localStorage.token : "")

  const [loginCredentials, setLoginCredentials] = useState({
    email: "",
    password: "",
  });

  const login = async () => {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/login", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        user: {
          email: loginCredentials.email,
          password: loginCredentials.password,
        },
      }),
    });
    if (res.ok) {
      console.log(res.headers.get("Authorization"));
      localStorage.setItem("token", res.headers.get("Authorization"));
      return res.json();
    } 
  };
```

**LOGIN COMPONENT**

```
const ctx = useAppContext(AppContext);
const { loginCredentials, setLoginCredentials, login, token } = ctx;
```

I am new to NextJS and web development in general. Thank you!

Comment: The statement `typeof window !== "undefined" ? localStorage.token : ""` returns different things on the server and on the client. Set the `token` state variable inside a `useEffect` instead. See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div).

Comment: Thanks, indeed, using a useEffect solved the issue!