# Nextjs: Warning: Prop `src` did not match

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

```
<img src={"/upload/images/"+Currency.getCurrent()+".svg"} />
```

And this my function:

```
static getCurrent() {
    var currency = "usd"
    const cookies = parseCookies()
    if (cookies.currency) {
        currency = cookies.currency
    }
    return currency
}
```

I get this error:

```
next-dev.js?3515:32 Warning: Prop `src` did not match. Server: "/upload/images/usd.svg" Client: "/upload/images/btc.svg"
```

So, `usd.svg` and `btc.svg` are exists.

For `usd` I dont have any error, but for `btc` I get error.

Note: This code return true url:

```
console.log(Currency.getCurrent()) // /upload/images/btc.svg
```

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div)? You should move the `Currency.getCurrent()` value to a state variable (`useState`) and set it inside a `useEffect`.