# nextjs: Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "x" Client: "y"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

This is my code:

```
export default function Nav() {
    const { userLogin } = useUser()
    console.log(userLogin)
    
    return (
        <nav className={styles.nav}>
            {!userLogin ? (
                <Link href={"/login"}><a className={`${styles.top}`}></a></Link>
            ) : (
                <Link href={"/profile"}><a className={`${styles.userLogged}`}></a></Link>
            )}
        </nav>
    )
}
```

And this is `useUser`:

```
export default function useUser(){
    var userLogin = false

    const cookies = parseCookies()
    if (cookies.token) {
        userLogin = true
    }

    return { userLogin }
}
```

So, if `userLogin` is `false`, everything is OK.

But if `userLogin` is `true` I get this error:

```
Warning: Prop `className` did not match. Server: "x" Client: "y"
```

This error show when I use cookies.

I don't want to use `next/dynamic`. because `dynamic` reload component again on click.

Comment: Please show the parseCookies code, so we can understand the whole picture better

Comment: @Daniel I use https://github.com/maticzav/nookies

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div)? Try moving the `parseCookies` logic inside a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If parseCookies happen only client-side, aka, uses `document` then next will have different HTML from the client, this happens to me with localStorage because I'm using `window`.

But because you are using cookies you can get them from getInitialProps's req argument:

```
App.getInitialProps = async ({ ctx }) => {
  const { req } = ctx;

  const cookies = parseCookies(req ? req.headers.cookie : document.cookie);

  return {
    pageProps:  { cookies }
  };
};
```

If you are using `nookies` they have a cool integration with Next.js
which allows you to pass the `ctx` as the first argument like so:
`const cookies = parseCookies(ctx)` and `ctx` will come from getInitialProps or getServerSideProps

see https://github.com/maticzav/nookies/blob/c4b1ca461e7b04877d295cb740fa8cbc1db2ad36/packages/nookies/src/index.ts?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container%2C%20div%5Bitemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FSoftwareSourceCode%22%5D%20main%2C%20%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D#L15

Comment: How can I fix it?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. but how can I custom it with my code? where I have to use `App.getInitialProps`?

Comment: App.getInitialProps is a static property of the App component which is in the _app.js file

Comment: Thank you. I can get the cookies. but how this solution work in `function useUser()`?

Comment: @RezMohsnei, you don't need to use `useUser()` function, since you have already the `cookies` in the App component as a prop. Just check the cookies in your component `const userLogin = !!cookies.token`;