# How to use useContext and Cookies together correctly from server?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, js-cookie

For context, I am able to use useContext and js-cookies to render/save the changes in client-side, but since I am not able to access the cookies from the server-side loading in the stateContext.js, the initial values saved to the state are always the empty ones. This causes a hydration error every time I refresh the page.

As a way to crudely fix this, in getServerSideProps I get the state cookies from the req in context (which I believe i don't have access to it in stateContext.js) and put it as a prop. Then I check if the state obtained from useContext has the empty state, and change it if so. Still, I do feel like I'm missing something with this implementation. Thanks

_app.js

```
import { StateProvider } from '../utils/cart/stateContext'

const MyApp = (props) => {
  const { Component, emotionCache = clientSideEmotionCache, pageProps } = props;

  return (
    <CacheProvider value={emotionCache}>
      <ThemeProvider theme={themeMode}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <StateProvider>
          <Component {...pageProps}/>
        </StateProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
    </CacheProvider>
  );
};
```

stateContext.js

```
import React, { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

export const StateContext = createContext();

const emptyState = {
    cart: {
        cartItems:[]
    },
    initial: true
}

function reducer(state, action) {
    state.initial = false
    // removed some irrelevant code
    return state;
}

export const StateProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const initialState = Cookies.get('state') ?  JSON.parse(Cookies.get('state')) : emptyState
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    
    useEffect(() => {
        Cookies.set("state", JSON.stringify(state));
    }, [state]);

    return (
        <StateContext.Provider value={{ state, dispatch }}>
            {children}
        </StateContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

index.js

```
import { StateContext } from '../utils/cart/stateContext';
const db = require('../models/index.js');
const Products = db.products;

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const products = await Products.findAll();
  const stateServ = JSON.parse(context.req.cookies.state ?? "{}");

  return {
    props: {
      products: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(products)),
      stateServ
    }
  }
}

export default function Home({products, stateServ}) {
  let { state } = useContext(StateContext)
  if (state.initial && Object.keys(stateServ).length) {
        state = stateServ;
  }

  return (
    <Layout state={state}>
      <div>
        <h1>Products</h1>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

Layout.js uses it in the navbar like so

```
<Link>{state.cart.cartItems.length > 0 ? (<Badge color="secondary" badgeContent={state.cart.cartItems.length}>Cart</Badge>) : ('Cart')}</Link>
```

EDIT:
As pointed out by @juliomalves, importing Layout with `{ ssr: false }` is enough to remove the hydration error, so using `getServerSideProps` to send the state is unnecessary:

```
const Layout = dynamic(
    () => import('../components/Layout'),
    { ssr: false }
)
```

Comment: Using `getServerSideProps` like you did would be a way to solve the issue if you want the initial state to depend on the cookie value. The other alternative is to not have the initial state depend on cookies whatsoever, and set the state value with the cookie value inside a `useEffect`. See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div).

Comment: @juliomalves Using `useEffect` along with `useContext` seems a bit confusing to me, but the second answer of using `next-dynamic` with `{ ssr: false }` for loading the `Layout` component worked nicely. Thanks for the answer, do you know if one way is faster than the other? Regardless I think I'll go with using `next-dynamic` since it's less code and looks simpler.

Comment: _"do you know if one way is faster than the other?"_ - not sure what you mean by faster, but they'd both load the code dynamically on the client only. There shouldn't be much difference between the two.

Comment: Wouldn't using `getServerSideProps` load it initially from the server? Though I imagine there really isn't much difference. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Yes, passing the cookie from `getServerSideProps` would also solve the hydration warning. However, that would imply that all your pages would use `getServerSideProps` and you'd need to pass it down to the `StateProvider` component.