# Expected server HTML to contain a matching <div> in <div>

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm using Nextjs and encountered this error which causes a lot of problems on my website. It makes layout mess. as I investigated my device detection hook is causing this problem. this is
hook:

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'
const getMatches = (query: string): boolean => {
if (isBrowser) {
    return window.matchMedia(query).matches
}
return false
```

}

```
const useMediaQuery = (range: [number?, any?]): boolean => {
 const [minWidth, maxWidth] = range

const query = `screen and (min-width: ${minWidth ?? 0}px) ${
    maxWidth
        ? `and (max-width: ${
              typeof maxWidth === 'string'
                  ? parseInt(maxWidth, 10)
                  : maxWidth
          }px)`
        : ''
} `

const [shouldMatch, setShouldMatch] = useState(() => getMatches(query))

useEffect(() => {
    let isActive = true

    const matchMedia = window.matchMedia(query)

    const updateMatch = () => {
        if (isActive) {
            setShouldMatch(getMatches(query))
        }
    }

    updateMatch()

    matchMedia.addEventListener('change', updateMatch)

    return () => {
        matchMedia.removeEventListener('change', updateMatch)
        isActive = false
    }
}, [query])

return shouldMatch
}
```

Can anyone help me what causes this warning?

this is how error looks like:
[see error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egLRx.png)

usage of hook in code

```
  const isTablet = useMediaQuery([0, TABLET])

   {!isTablet && (
                  <Fade shouldShow={isActive}>
                    <img
                       alt={service?.title}
                       className="nox-service-icon"
                       src={service?.icon}
                      />
                   </Fade>)}
```

Comment: Remove `() => getMatches(query)` from inside the `useState()` initialisation. That's what's causing the mismatch because `getMatches(query)` returns different things on the server (when the page gets pre-rendered) and on the client (during client-side hydration). See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div).

Answer (score 0):

After some cleaning I ended up with this. The reason might be because you're still using `window.matchMedia` in the useEffect. But I'm not 100% sure since you didn't share the error you're getting.

```
const isBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'

const useMediaQuery = (range: [number?, any?]): boolean => {
  const [minWidth, maxWidth] = range

  const query = `screen and (min-width: ${minWidth ?? 0}px)${
    maxWidth
      ? ` and (max-width: ${
        typeof maxWidth === 'string'
          ? parseInt(maxWidth, 10)
          : maxWidth
      }px)`
      : ''
  }`;
  
  const matchMedia = useMemo(() => isBrowser && window.matchMedia(query), [query]);
  const [shouldMatch, setShouldMatch] = useState(matchMedia && matchMedia.matches);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!matchMedia) return;
    
    const listener = () => setShouldMatch(matchMedia.matches);
    
    matchMedia.addEventListener('change', listener)

    return () => matchMedia.removeEventListener('change', listener)
  }, [matchMedia])

  return shouldMatch
}
```

Comment: same result... btw I uploaded error message and hook usage in question.