# Next JS Date Time Counter Hydration Issue

Tags: datetime, next.js, counter, hydration

I'm attempting to display/format a datetime counter in NextJS but am encountering hydration issues. The following should work, no?

`next-dev.js?3515:24 Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "01:07:28" Client: "01:07:29"`

```
import { useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {

  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(() => {
    const hour = ("0" + new Date().getUTCHours()).slice(-2);
    const minutes = ("0" + new Date().getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
    const seconds = ("0" + new Date().getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);

    return `${hour}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  });

  return (
      <span>
          {currentTime}
      </span>
  );
}

export default MyApp;
```

Comment: The mismatch occurs because the initial state value for `currentTime` will be different when the page gets pre-rendered on the server, and when the page gets hydrated on the client. You should move setting the `currentTime` state value inside a `useEffect` to avoid the issue. See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div).