# window.innerWidth is causing a Hydration error

Tags: typescript, next.js

```
export default function UseWindowSize() {
    const isClient = typeof window === 'object';
    const lastWidth = useRef<number>();

    const getSize = useCallback((): number | undefined => isClient ? window.innerWidth : undefined, [ isClient ]);

    const [ windowSize, setWindowSize ] = useState(getSize);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isClient) {
            return undefined;
        }

        function handleResize() {
            if (window?.innerWidth !== lastWidth.current) {
                const width = getSize();
                lastWidth.current = width;
                setWindowSize(width);
            }
        }
        window.addEventListener('resize', handleResize);
        return () => window.removeEventListener('resize', handleResize);
    }, [ getSize, isClient ]);

    return windowSize;
};
```

I am using this function to get the width of the window and know which component to render but it's causing some issues `Warning: Prop 'className' did not match. Server: "mobile-header" Client: "header"` and `Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`.

console.log from the devtool shows width numbers correctly while from server console it shows undefined which I think is causing this class mismatch

Comment: The mismatch happens because `getSize` returns different values when the page gets pre-rendered on the server, and when the page gets hydrated on the client. Do not use `getSize` to initialise your `useState`, just do `const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState();`. See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div).