# How to use localStorage in Next.js and not get a hydration error?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I want to use the local storage to save a token and access it,

My code looks like this :

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    localStorage.setItem(key,value)
}
```

If I don't use the part that checks type of window i get the error :

> localStorage is not defined

But that seems to lead to the error mentioned [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error) in the docs which can be fixed by removing the typeof window check as that seems to cause the hydration error when I refresh the page  which is:

> Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Any idea on what to do here?

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try accessing `localStorage` within a `useEffect()`:

```js
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem(key, value);
}, []);
```

Comment: I believe that the if condition is not needed in this case, but this is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have updated the answer.

Comment: What if I'm using https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage, which already uses `useEffect`? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/q/74022328/470749