# How to solve react-hydration-error in Next.js when using `useLocalStorage` and `useDebounce`

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, local-storage

When I try to use https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-local-storage in Next.js in the following way, I get

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: Text content does not match
> server-rendered HTML.
>
> See more info here:
> https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

```js
  const [toleranceH, setToleranceH] = useLocalStorage<number>('toleranceH', 3);
  const [toleranceS, setToleranceS] = useLocalStorage<number>('toleranceS', 3);
  const [toleranceL, setToleranceL] = useLocalStorage<number>('toleranceL', 3);

  const [results, setResults] = useState<MegaColor[]>([]);

  const debouncedToleranceH = useDebounce<number>(toleranceH, 200);
  const debouncedToleranceS = useDebounce<number>(toleranceS, 200);
  const debouncedToleranceL = useDebounce<number>(toleranceL, 200);

  useEffect(() => {
    const targetColorDetailsObject = getColorDetailsObject(targetColor);
    const degreeTolerance = (360 / 100) * debouncedToleranceH;
    const [hueMin, hueMax] = getHueTolerance(targetColorDetailsObject.hue(), degreeTolerance);
    const filteredColors = getFilteredColors(targetColorDetailsObject, loadedMegaColors, hueMin, hueMax, debouncedToleranceS, debouncedToleranceL);
    setResults(filteredColors);
    return () => {
      // console.log('cleanup');
    };
  }, [targetColor, loadedMegaColors, debouncedToleranceH, debouncedToleranceS, debouncedToleranceL]);
```

From that help page, I still can't figure out what to adjust so that I can use both `useLocalStorage` and `useDebounce`.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/73411103/470749 but don't want to forcefully set a localStorage value (it should only be set by the user).

Comment: some implementation of useLocalStorage now support ssr, namely [react-hookz](https://react-hookz.github.io/web/?path=/docs/side-effect-uselocalstoragevalue--example). It does so by providing the original value on the first render, and updating the value immediately.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest checking out this excellent [post](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/) on rehydration by Josh W Comeau.

Since Next.js pre-renders every page by default you need to ensure that the component in which you are calling `window.localstorage` is only rendered on the client.

A simple solution is to:

1. Keep a `hasMounted` state

```js
const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = useState(false);
```

2. Toggle it inside a `useEffect`

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // This will only be called once the component is mounted inside the browser
  setHasMounted(true);
}, []);
```

3. Add a check so that Next.js won't complain about prerendering stuff on the server that won't match the stuff that gets rendered on the client

```
if (!hasMounted) {
  return null;
}
```

4. Ensure that the client-side stuff comes after the check

To make it more reusable you could use one of these two methods which  essentially do the same:

#### ClientOnly Component

```
function ClientOnly({ children, ...delegated }) {
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }, []);
  if (!hasMounted) {
    return null;
  }
  /**
   * Could also replace the <div></div> with
   * <></> and remove ...delegated if no need
   */
  return (
    <div {...delegated}> 
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}

...

<ClientOnly>
  <MyComponent /> // <--- client only stuff, safe to use useLocalStorage in here
</ClientOnly>
```

or

#### Custom useHasMounted hook

```js
function useHasMounted() {
  const [hasMounted, setHasMounted] = React.useState(false);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setHasMounted(true);
  }, []);
  return hasMounted;
}

...

function ParentComponent() {  
  const hasMounted = useHasMounted();
  if (!hasMounted) {
    return null;
  }
  return (
    <MyComponent />
  );
}

...

function MyComponent() {
  const [toleranceH, setToleranceH] = useLocalStorage<number>('toleranceH', 3);
  const [toleranceS, setToleranceS] = useLocalStorage<number>('toleranceS', 3);
  const [toleranceL, setToleranceL] = useLocalStorage<number>('toleranceL', 3);

  ...
}

...
```

##### Note:

By overdoing this or using this method at the top level of your component tree, you are killing the Next.js prerendering capabilities and turning your app into more of a "client-side heavy" app (see [performance implications](https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#performance-implications)). If you are using `window.localstorage` (outside of components, where you don't have `useEffect` available), you should always wrap with:

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  // client-side code
}
```

Comment: Thanks! The `<ClientOnly>` approach seemed to work. The `useHasMounted ` approach broke this rule https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html, as did `if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
     return null;
   }` (as the article predicted at Noble But Flawed Attempt https://www.joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/#a-noble-but-flawed-attempt).

Comment: Ah yes I'm sorry, I've edited my answer, best to wrap it with a parent component with the `useHasMounted` approach, so that no condition that returns in the component is above some other hook calls. As for the `typeof widow` check, I only found use for it outside of components, next might give you errors on the server like `localStorage is not defined` otherwise.