# How to solve "Unhandled Runtime Error" in Next.js 13.4, typescript. | simple math app

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I have two issues in my code that I can't solve.
[image: First]
[image: second]

My app generates two random numbers, checks if they are divisible without a remainder, and checks if the user entered the correct answer.

```
'use client';

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { randomOneToHundred, randomOneToTen } from './Randoms/randomNumbers';

const DivisionQuestion = () => {
    const [userAnswer, setUserAnswer] = useState('');

    // Перевірка чисел на ділення без остачі

    const [numberX, setNumberX] = useState<number | null>(null);
    const [numberY, setNumberY] = useState<number | null>(null);
    // Функція для перевірки

    const checkDivision = (a: number, b: number): boolean => {
        return a % b === 0;
    };

    function checkNumbers() {
        const randomNum1 = randomOneToHundred();
        const randomNum2 = randomOneToTen();

        if (checkDivision(randomNum1, randomNum2)) {
            setNumberX(randomNum1);
            setNumberY(randomNum2);
        } else {
            checkNumbers();
        }
    }
    if (numberX === null || numberY === null) {
        checkNumbers();
    }

    const correctAnswer: number = numberX !== null && numberY !== null ? numberX / numberY : 0;

    const handleAnswerChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setUserAnswer(event.target.value);
    };

    const checkAnswer = () => {
        if (userAnswer === '') {
            return null;
        }
        const userEnteredNumber = parseFloat(userAnswer);
        if (!isNaN(userEnteredNumber) && userEnteredNumber === correctAnswer) {
            return <p className='text-green-500'>Відповідь правильна!</p>;
        } else {
            return <p className='text-red-500'>Спробуйте ще раз.</p>;
        }
    };

    return (
        <section className=''>
            <p className='dark:text-white'>
                Ділення {numberX} / {numberY}
            </p>
            <p>
                Скільки буде {numberX} поділити на {numberY}?
            </p>
            <input
                type='text'
                value={userAnswer}
                autoComplete='off'
                onChange={handleAnswerChange}
                className=''
            />
            <div className='mt-3'>{checkAnswer()}</div>
        </section>
    );
};

export default DivisionQuestion;
```

I also use

```
<html lang='en' suppressHydrationWarning>
```

in my layout.

Is it best to run this component on the server, but I don't know how to do it? I also have to admit, that the error appears only when the page is reloaded,  during the initial rendering, there is no such problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please post code, **error messages**, markup, data structures, and other textual information **as text**, not just as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: You can either opt out of server side rendering for this page or check if it is rendering on the server. If it is, just don't render anything.

Comment: Here is a bit of [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74022328/how-to-solve-react-hydration-error-in-next-js-when-using-uselocalstorage-and) about kelsny's comment.