# React custom localstorage hook hydration error in NextJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I am trying to implement the `localstorage` hook in NextJS, but getting the following error: `Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.`. Any ideas of what might cause it? To me, it looks like the `useEffect` function is not properly used. How do I force the CSR instead of SSR to avoid the hydration error?

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useLocalStorage<T>(key: string, initialValue: T) {
    const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState<T>(() => {
        if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
            return initialValue;
        }
        try {
            const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
            return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
        } catch (error) {
            return initialValue;
        }
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        setStoredValue(storedValue);
    }, [storedValue, setStoredValue]);

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const setValue = (value: T | ((val: T) => T)) => {
        try {
            const valueToStore = value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
            setStoredValue(valueToStore);

            if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
                window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
            }
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    };

    return [storedValue, setValue] as const;
}

export default useLocalStorage;
```

Comment: Check about this disccussion about the error https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/35773

Comment: You get the hydration error because the initial state you set for the `storedValue` state variable is different on the server and on the client. Try setting the initial state for that variable inside a `useEffect` instead. See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div).

Answer (score 3):

Try this version of the hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const isServer = typeof window === 'undefined';

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  // State to store our value
  // Pass initial state function to useState so logic is only executed once
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(() => initialValue);

  const initialize = () => {
    if (isServer) {
      return initialValue;
    }
    try {
      // Get from local storage by key
      const item = window.localStorage.getItem(key);
      // Parse stored json or if none return initialValue
      return item ? JSON.parse(item) : initialValue;
    } catch (error) {
      // If error also return initialValue
      console.log(error);
      return initialValue;
    }
  };

  /* prevents hydration error so that state is only initialized after server is defined */
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isServer) {
      setStoredValue(initialize());
    }
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, []);

  // Return a wrapped version of useState's setter function that ...
  // ... persists the new value to localStorage.
  const setValue = (value) => {
    try {
      // Allow value to be a function so we have same API as useState
      const valueToStore =
        value instanceof Function ? value(storedValue) : value;
      // Save state
      setStoredValue(valueToStore);
      // Save to local storage
      if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
        window.localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(valueToStore));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // A more advanced implementation would handle the error case
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return [storedValue, setValue];
}
```

Comment: This seems copied from somewhere else. Would be great if you linked the original source

Comment: @MikeSzyndel I am the original source. Its my answer in two places :)

Comment: This saved my ass! Thanks so much! What did you change to make it work?

Comment: The check inside initialize function seems to be redundant if it's invoked only under `!isServer` condition. And I don't think you need `isServer` check at all since `useEffect` will be running on client only anyway. Also `useState(() => initialValue)` is the same as `useState(initialValue)` in this case, if your intention was to be able to pass a function to the hook it won't going to work since the function will have to be invoked and will be invoked on every render, you have to check-invoke it inside useState.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways which i know to remove Hydration error.

First is to use next/dynamic and load dynamically with ssr option passes as false like this :

```
   import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

   const DynamicHeader = dynamic(() => import('../components/header'), {
     ssr: false,
   })
```

But as this is a custom hook and we can only import Component dynamically so you have to use useEffect correctly in this case !

Second is to use useEffect hook. I have done this in Js Hope this helps !

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
const [value, setValue] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
const data = localStorage.getItem(key);
if (data === null) {
  if (typeof initialValue === "function") {
    setValue(initialValue());
  } else {
    setValue(initialValue);
  }
 } else {
  setValue(JSON.parse(data));
 }
 }, []);

 useEffect(() => {
     localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
 }, [value]);

 return [value, setValue];
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Zustand seems to have a solution for this, im currently using Next 13 app router. i was having similar issues so went to zustand docs, there is property called `skipHydration` which can be used to control when the hydration occurs.

what i did was , made a client component called Hydrations, and i have imported all my zustand stores and called the `rehydrate` function , [Zustand docs](https://github.com/pmndrs/zustand/blob/main/docs/integrations/persisting-store-data.md#skiphydration)

**Auth slice**

```
    import { create } from 'zustand';
import { persist } from 'zustand/middleware';

interface TypeAuth {
    admin: TypeAdmin | null;
    setAdmin: (admin: TypeAdmin) => void;
}

const useAuth = create<TypeAuth>()(
    persist(
        (set) => ({
            admin: null,
            setAdmin: (admin) => {
                set({ admin });
            },
        }),
        {
            name: 'auth',
            skipHydration: true,
        }
    )
);

export default useAuth;
```

Hydration File

```
'use client';

import { useEffect } from 'react';

import { useAuth } from '@/utils/slices';

export default function Hydrations() {
    useEffect(() => {
        useAuth.persist.rehydrate();
    }, []);

    return null;
}
```

Now just import this Hydration File in your root layout