# Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match

Tags: next.js, hydration

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { logout } from '../store/userSlice';
import Link from 'next/link';

export default function Navbar() {
  const currentUser = useSelector((state) => state.user.currentUser);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    dispatch(logout());
    router.push('/login');
  };

  const renderAuthLinks = () => {
    if (currentUser) {
      return (
        <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>
      );
    } else {
      return (
        <Link href="/login">Login</Link>
      );
    }
  };

  return (

    <>
      <section>
        <div>
          <div>
            <Link href="/">Home</Link>
          </div>
          <div>
            {currentUser ?
              (<button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button>)
              :
              (<Link href="/login">Login</Link>)
            }
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}
```

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching  in .

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Component Stack
button
div
div
section
Navbar
Provider
MyApp

....................................

Comment: Hydration mismatches are mostly caused by invalid DOM nesting, however this components markup looks valid to me. Check your other components.

Comment: It is possible that localStorage is causing the hydration errors. Take a look at this thread and see if it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73944543/react-custom-localstorage-hook-hydration-error-in-nextjs