# SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined Error in NextJS

Tags: javascript, next.js, speech-synthesis

I'm trying to get the 'SpeechSynthesis to speak 'Hello world' but it gives me an error. *SpeechSynthesisUtterance is not defined*. When I first try it it works but when I restart the server with 'npm run dev' it gives the error.

Is there a way I can fix this?

Here's the code:

```js
export default function Main() {
  let text = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world!");

  return <button onClick={SpeechSynthesis.speak(text)}>Click me</button>;
}
```

Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Next.js pre-renders all pages on the server by default. `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` won't be available on the server since it's a Web API present on the browser only. See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div) for potential workarounds.

Comment: Alternatively, you can move the `text` variable declaration to the `onClick` handler, e.g. `onClick={() => { SpeechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world!")); }}`.

Answer (score 0):

The `window` and `SpeechSynthesisUtterance` can not be accessed in server side, so move them to client-side rendering, like this:

```js
<button
  onClick={() => {
    window.speechSynthesis.speak(new SpeechSynthesisUtterance("Hello world!"))
  }}
>
  Click me
</button>
```