# How to fix error, "Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML." in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, next.js, server-side-rendering

I am following a tutorial but got stuck with this issue along the way, `Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.`. I saw some solutions after some searches I made, which one was setting the SSR to false, but I need another method for this.

Here's my code and I highly suspected the `currentPlayer` state to be causing the issue, the function of that is to take turns of the two players, X and O.

index.tsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const Board = () => {
  const [currentPlayer, setCurrentPlayer] = useState<"X" | "O">(
    Math.round(Math.random() * 1) === 1 ? "X" : "O",
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Hey {currentPlayer}, it is your turn.</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Board;
```

I came accross a solution that uses useEffect, but I am not sure how that's applicable in my code.

Comment: _"I came accross a solution that uses useEffect, but I am not sure how that's applicable in my code"_ - You set the value of `currentPlayer` inside the `useEffect` rather than initialising it in the `useState`. This forces its random value to only be set on the client-side, preventing the hydration error.

Comment: @juliomalves, does that means I will be having a useState inside a useEffect?

Comment: No. You keep the `useState` where it is but do not initialise the state there. Then inside `useEffect` you call `setCurrentPlayer` with the random value. Similar to what's recommended here in the first approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66374800/1870780.

Comment: useState initial state getter will run both on server and in browser, and potentially result in different values, so my question to you: please calculate probability of getting same results of Math.random > 0.5 twice a row :). If talking seriously: use empty default value for useState, and initialize it in useEffect, in this case code will be run one - in browser