# Migration from CRA to NextJS - Dynamic CSS Class - Warning: Prop `className` did not match

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js

I am new to Next.js and trying to migrate my Create React App over to Next. Now I have certain CSS styles that are being applied conditionally based on whether the screen is considered to be small enough for mobile or not. This variable ('isMobile') is part of the state and is defined based on the screen width. Now whenever I reload the page, I am getting a mismatch in classname between Server and Client (the same happens within the 'createAdditionalColClasses' function in the component. I have tried many solutions to remove this Warning but can't seem to be able to make it work. I am running **Next 13.0.2** and **React 18.2.0**.

My index.js

```
class Index extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      title: "",
      forms: {
        search: {
          data: {
            title: "",
            searchLimitTo: (typeof window !== "undefined" &&
              JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("forms")) &&
              JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("forms")).search.data
                .searchLimitTo) || {
              rn: true,
              ing: true
            }
          },
          errors: {}
        }
      },
      isMobile: typeof window !== "undefined" && window.innerWidth < 865
    };
    if (
      typeof window !== "undefined" &&
      !window.localStorage.getItem("forms")
    ) {
      let forms = {
        filters: this.state.filters,
        sortedBy: this.state.sortedBy,
        search: {
          data: {
            searchLimitTo: {
              rn: true,
              ing: true
            }
          }
        }
      };
      window.localStorage.setItem("forms", JSON.stringify(forms));
    }
    toast.dismiss();
  }

  setState(state) {
    let localState = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("forms"));
    for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(state)) {
      if (key === "forms") {
        for (let [k, v] of Object.entries(value)) {
          if (["filters", "sortedBy"].includes(k)) {
            localState[k] = v;
          } else if (k === "search") {
            localState[k]["data"]["searchLimitTo"] = v.data.searchLimitTo;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    window.localStorage.setItem("forms", JSON.stringify(localState));
    super.setState(state);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener(
      "resize",
      () => {
        this.setState({
          isMobile: window.innerWidth < 865
        });
      },
      false
    );
  }

  createAdditionalColClasses = () => {
    const { isMobile } = this.state;
    const additionaClasses = isMobile
      ? "mx-auto"
      : "ms-auto me-5 mx-xl-auto ps-5";
    return additionaClasses;
  };

  render() {
    const { isMobile } = this.state;
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
          <div className={styles["outter-first-div"]}>
            <div className={`background`}></div>
            <style jsx>{`
              .background {
                background: ${isMobile
                  ? `url(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMG_MOBILE}) center / contain no-repeat`
                  : `url(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_IMG_DESKTOP}) center / contain no-repeat`};
                  height: 100vh;
                  width: 100vw;
                  position: absolute;
                  z-index: -100;
                  padding: 0;
                  margin: 0;
                  top: 0;
                  left: 0;
              }
            `}</style>
            <div className={styles.items}>
              <div className="">
                <div className="row">
                  <div
                    className={`col-11 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-lg-7 col-xl-6 text-center ${this.createAdditionalColClasses()} ${
                      styles["initial-search-form-input-div"]
                    }`}
                  >
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```

My next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  compiler: {
    // Enables the styled-components SWC transform
    styledComponents: true
  }
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

On Stackoverflow I saw several answers addressing this problem by changing the next.config.js to the above but unfortunately it did not work in my case.

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Comment: The mismatch problem occurs because you're initialising state values based on the presence of `window` (which differs on the server and client). You should move that logic to `componentDidMount` instead. See [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div).

Comment: Hi @juliomalves, thanks for the response. The logic decides over quite a bit of the styling though, and componentDidMount is only applied after the component is rendered, so the design will be displayed wrong for a splitsecond and will then jump. Is there any way I can add it to cdm without this jump, maybe by somehow delaying the rendering?