# Next.js "Text content did not match"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have component in Next.js which displays data pulled from a database, this is all fine. The problem occurs when I attempt to format the dates, I get the following warning `Warning: Text content did not match.` I roughly understand that it's to do with the client data being out of sync with the server data but I'm not sure the best approach to fix it. I have seen a solution using `useEffect` but my knowledge of this hook is still a little basic.

My current thinking is to format the dates and then add them to the `projects` object, then they can be mapped out with the rest of the data, does that sound like a valid idea?

Here's what I currently have:

```js
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

export default function ProjectList(props) {
  const [projects, setProjects] = useState(props.projects.data);
  
  // format the date
  function formatStartDate(startDate) {
    return Intl.DateTimeFormat('default', {
      month: 'short',
      day: '2-digit',
      hour: '2-digit',
      minute: '2-digit',
    }).format(new Date(startDate));
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    setProjects(props.projects.data);
  }, [props]);

  return (
    projects.length > 0 && (
      <>
        {projects &&
          projects.map((project) => (
            <div key={project.id}>
              <h2> {project.attributes.project_name}</h2>
              <p>{formatStartDate(project.attributes.start_date)}</p>
            </div>
          ))}
      </>
    )
  );
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div)

Comment: Hi @Konrad I've been looking at that post. It does partly answer my question I think, but I have the added complication of formatting the date and looping through the map. I'm struggling to work these two together.