# Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "562" Client: "563" when creating a timer in Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

I want to implement a **competition clock** using Nextjs:

1. `competitionStartTime` represents the competition start time
2. While the user enters the page, I save `Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) - competitionStartTime` (how long does the competition ran)
3. Using `addOneSecond` and `setInterval` keep adding one to `competitionStartTime` to run the timer every second.
4. It also has a pause function for using to pause and resume the timer

My full demo code:

```js
"use client";

import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";

function calculateModelResult(duration) {
  // simulate the model calculation time, it costs 0.3s
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
    duration + 0;
  }
  return duration * 0.1;
}

export default function Page() {
  const competitionStartTime = 1692956171;
  const [competitionRunningTime, setCompetitionRunningTime] = useState(
    Math.round(Date.now() / 1000) - competitionStartTime
  );
  const [modelResult, setModelResult] = useState(0);
  const modelIntervalRef = useRef(0);
  const competitionTimeIntervalRef = useRef(0);
  const [pause, setPause] = useState(false);
  const addOneSecond = () => setCompetitionRunningTime((prev) => prev + 1);

  useEffect(() => {
    modelIntervalRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
      setModelResult(calculateModelResult(competitionRunningTime));
    }, 1000);

    competitionTimeIntervalRef.current = window.setInterval(() => {
      addOneSecond();
      console.log(competitionRunningTime);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      window.clearInterval(modelIntervalRef.current);
      window.clearInterval(competitionTimeIntervalRef.current);
    };
  }, [competitionRunningTime]);

  const pasueFunction = () => {
    if (!pause) {
      clearInterval(competitionTimeIntervalRef.current);
    } else {
      competitionTimeIntervalRef.current = setInterval(addOneSecond, 1000);
    }
    setPause((prev) => !prev);
  };
  return (
    <>
      <h1>
        Hello, the time of the match is {competitionRunningTime}, the model result is {modelResult}.
      </h1>
      <button onClick={pasueFunction}>{pause ? "Run" : "Pause"}</button>
    </>
  );
}
```

However, I am two errors:

```
Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML.

Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "562" Client: "563"

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

```
Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
```

And the `modelResult` appears to has delay:

```
Hello, the time of the match is 2904, the model result is 290.3.
Hello, the time of the match is 2938, the model result is 293.7.
```

It needs to be calculated using the `competitionRunningTime` and it costs 0.3s to finish the calculation, will it affect the time update every second?

I have watched [warning text content did not match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div), it didn't help with my current code. May I ask how can I solve it?

Comment: please read the doc first, https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Comment: Can you clarify how [Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "I'm out" Client: "I'm in" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66374123/warning-text-content-did-not-match-server-im-out-client-im-in-div) did not address the issue? Your problem is with `Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)`. Moving the `competitionRunningTime` initialisation to a `useEffect` will solve the hydration error.